# backbone alternative syntax

Tags: backbone.js, syntax

I come from php where I can right alternative syntax if else statements like

```
<?php if(): ?>
    // conditional html goes here
<?php endif;?>
```

My question is if there is a way to do the same thing on a backbone view like

```
<% if(condition): %>
    html code goes here ;

<% endif; %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the default [Underscore templates](http://underscorejs.org/#template) then:

```
<% if(condition) { %>
    HTML goes here
<% } %>
```

Don't forget the `{` and `}` or you'll wind up with a mess.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/W33Tw/

Answer (score 0):

This question should really be tagged with whatever template solution you are using with backbone. If you are using handlebars (which is awesome http://handlebarsjs.com/ ), you can do that with:

```
{{#if contextPropertyThatEvaluatesSanelyAsABoolean}}
  your html!
{{else}}
  different html!
{{/if}}
```

and then pass in a context like:

```
$(@el).html(this.template({
  contextPropertyThatEvaluatesSanelyAsABoolean: true
}))
```

or if you are using coffeescript:

```
$(@el).html @template
  contextPropertyThatEvaluatesSanelyAsABoolean: true
```

There are similar solutions for other templating languages too.